# errors in installing cryptography-40.0.2 python (3.11.3) package in an offline environment in Redhat Linux 7.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cryptography

When installing the cryptography python package in an offline environment (no internet), it is failing and trying to access github.com

The error is: failed to connect to github.com: Connection timed outL class=0s (2)

The command I have ran is python -m pip install cryptography*.whl

Below is the full screenshot of the error:

We cannot open the servers to the internet and github.com due to security policy.

Is there other way to install this package without internet?

I have downloaded crates.io-index locally into server but could have not seen any references online on what can be done for the cryptography installation to read the crates.io-index file locally.

Comment: Can you include the error message. But not as a screenshot. Copy/paste the complete error message. Which `.whl` file have you downloaded and from where?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.